# O que causa "Call to undefined function session_status()"?

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte erro:

> Call to undefined function session_status() in /home/a5872788/public_html/index.php on line 2

Por que ocorre esse erro? Essa não é uma função padrão do PHP?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque está em inglês.

Comment: Aparece-me este erro ao executar a página no filleZilla

Comment: Tentei dar uma editada para não piorar as coisas mas não deu; ele devia olhar no código e pelo menos procurar no Google alguma referência do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Se puder postar o código vai ficar mais fácil de ajuda-lo

Comment: Seu PHP é antigo, você precisa da versão 5.4 ou superior: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: ... e como assim "executar a página no filleZilla"? Você quis dizer Mozilla?

Comment: Apesar de já ter sido respondido, ficou um pouco confuso. session_status() é um recurso do PHP 5.4. Se um código com essa função for executado em qualquer versão inferior à 5.4 ela será considerada uma função de usuário a qual, como não foi implementada, produz esse erro de função indefinida. Quanto a relação com o fileZilla, que é um mero cliente de FTP para o caso, ele é quem está intermeando o arquivo local, que provavelmente já é 5.4 ou superior, com o servidor que com certeza deve ser 5.3 ou inferior.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto A pergunta foi reaberta, não quer postar seu comentário como resposta?

Comment: Se você sugere, por que não?

Answer (score 1):

Esta resposta [já foi dada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15421/o-que-causa-call-to-undefined-function-session-status?noredirect=1#comment29808_15421) em forma de comentário e, [conforme sugerido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15421/o-que-causa-call-to-undefined-function-session-status?noredirect=1#comment29755_15421), estarei adicionando-a como resposta também, além de melhor elaborá-la, com links e formatação.

[session_status()](http://php.net/session_status) é um recurso introduzido no PHP 5.4.

Se um código com essa função for executado em qualquer versão inferior à 5.4 ela será considerada uma [função definida pelo usuário](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) a qual, como não foi implementada e/ou não pôde ser automaticamente localizada, como que por include/require falho porém de erro suprimido, é disparado esse erro de função indefinida.

Quanto a relação com o [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org), que é um mero cliente de FTP para esse caso, ele é quem está intermeando o arquivo local, que provavelmente está em execução sob um servidor no qual o PHP instalado é de versão 5.4 ou superior, com o servidor que com certeza deve ser 5.3 ou inferior.